# Rails migration is giving NoMethodError and I do not see why

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I do not know why this is breaking. I'm trying to run a migration on some code I've inherited and I've hit a snag. Here is the error message followed by the migration file code.

```
==  AddStorecreditGizmoType: migrating ========================================
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_by_name' for GizmoCategory(id: integer, description: string):Class
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/base.rb:1876:in `method_missing'
/home/thefonso/site-dev/vendor/plugins/will_paginate/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:175:in `method_missing_with_paginate'
db/migrate//20090628000954_add_storecredit_gizmo_type.rb:4:in `up'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `block in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:365:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:457:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:409:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/tasks/databases.rake:135:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate:up
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is the migration file code

```
class AddStorecreditGizmoType < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    # TODO: GizmoCategory.find_by_name("misc") is breaking...why? Attempted to replace with "where" but same error.
    new = GizmoType.new(:name => "store_credit", :description => "Store Credit", :gizmo_category => GizmoCategory.find_by_name("misc"), :required_fee_cents => 0, :suggested_fee_cents => 0)
    new.save!
    DB.execute("UPDATE gizmo_contexts_gizmo_types SET gizmo_type_id = #{new.id} WHERE gizmo_type_id IN (SELECT id FROM gizmo_types WHERE name = 'gift_cert');")
  end

  def self.down
    DB.execute("UPDATE gizmo_contexts_gizmo_types SET gizmo_type_id = (SELECT id FROM gizmo_types WHERE name = 'gift_cert') WHERE gizmo_type_id IN (SELECT id FROM gizmo_types WHERE name = 'store_credit');")
    GizmoType.find_by_name("store_credit").destroy
  end
end
```

I've tried using "where" and "Find_by" but I keep getting this same "undefined method blahblah for GizmoCategory

Can you point me in the right direction? What am I missing? forgetting? What's happening here?

Oh and versions are as follows

- rails - 2.3.14
- ruby - 1.9.3p194

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find_by_*` methods didn't exist in [activerecord 2.3.14](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/v2.3.14/activerecord). Use `Model.find` instead.

```rb
category = GizmoCategory.find(:first, conditions: "name = 'store_credit'")
category.destroy if category
```

Comment: so would this section ":gizmo_category => GizmoCategory.find_by_name("misc")," become ":gizmo_category => GizmoCategory.find(:first, "misc")," ???

Comment: `GizmoCategory.find(:first, conditions: "name = 'misc'")`

Comment: well that did give me a new error "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "name" does not exist" . And in the Database, I can see the name column under the model "gizmo_types".  UPDATE: I see kind of the problem...I'm rebuilding this app from an existing app and I see on THAT other app, let's call it app PRIME. On prime the "gizmo_categories" model has a "name" column. So now it's a hunt to find out why that column is not in the rebuilt Dev app.

Comment: UPDATE: so I wrote another migration to create the missing name column and then re-ran this migration with the modifications to .find as mentioned above. It worked so listing this as solution